Postgres logical replication and table rename
We have a table in main DB that is getting logically replicated to another DB called SOR. We need to rename this table, and add a bunch of tables to the publication on the main DB. I tried this procedure

disable the subscriber on SOR DB
rename the (receiving) table on SOR DB
rename the table on main DB, also add the tables to the publication
re-enable subscriber on SOR DB
refresh the subscription ALTER SUBSCRIPTION my_subscription REFRESH PUBLICATION WITH (copy_data=false);

I waited for the replication slot on main DB to clear up, and then checked record count, SOR DB lost some data in this time window.
Is there a seamless way to rename a table in logical replication without losing data on the subscriber side ? Would (copy_data=true) help ?
Thank you !
some more details:

we use PG 14 on AWS RDS
The reason for this change is we are migrating a parent-child table into a partitioned table


You might receive a better response at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

thank you John, posted https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/339369/postgres-logical-replication-and-table-rename
